# How to color sets of row with equal first line cell header?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

My goal is to visually color rows with equal first line header (see attached photo)

The problem is:

1. the `Conditional formatting` feature only let you choose 1 color `solution: 1 color is enough`
2. The formula that I use checks from top to bottom. The bug are:

   1. the last row will always return `FALSE`. Consequently, the conditional formatting will not color that row with `green` (see attached photo)
   2. almost everything will be colored `green` instead of `green` and `blue`.

The formula:

```
=EQ(
  LEFT(D19, SEARCH(CHAR(10),D19)-1),
  LEFT(D20, SEARCH(CHAR(10),D20)-1)
 )
```

The logic I wish to write into a formula that maybe feasible for the `Conditional formatting` feature:

1. equal(D19 first line, D20 first line) => return true, increment 2nd parameter by 1
2. equal(D19 first line, D21 first line) => return true, increment 2nd parameter by 1
3. equal(D19 first line, D22 first line) => return true, increment 1st parameter by 1
4. equal(D19 first line, D23 first line) => return false, increment 1st parameter by X (in this case 3)
5. equal(D23 first line, D24 first line) => return true, increment 2nd parameter by 1

[image]

Comment: Are the values on the first line of column D limited to a fixed list? If so, you will need to create a conditional formatting rule for each value on this list. In case this value is dynamic, I'd recommend using Apps Scripts to achieve this due to conditional formatting limitations.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet